# VBA to click on a button on an IE form to submit it

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I'm quite new to VBA so please bear with me. I've been trying to create an automation to fill in username and password and login to a site (to start with) but I've been having trouble trying to click on the submit button. Scoured the internet and learnt a whole bunch of things but I didnt find anything that seems to work. The page loads and fills in the details and nothing happens when I run the code below.

Would greatly appreciate some help with this. Thanks in advance as always!

```
Sub worldcheck()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim cel As Range
Dim post As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim element As Object

Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
lastrow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.world-check.com/frontend/login/"

Do While IE.busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))

IE.document.getElementbyID("username").Value = ws.Range("D2")
IE.document.getElementbyID("password").Value = ws.Range("D3")
IE.document.getElementbyClass("button").click

Do While IE.busy
    DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You can try the `.fireevent('eventname')` so you could use `click` as your event name.  Also, looking at the source, ` <form action="/frontend/login/"` would also mean you could try `IE.document.form(0).submit` i believe

Comment: I agree with QHarr's answer. The error occurs on this line: `IE.document.getElementbyClass("button").click`. The right format should be `IE.document.getElementsbyClassName("button")(0).Click`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing else happens? You should be getting an error message at the very least as you are trying to use a non existent method (*VBA Run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method*) . The method is `getElementsByClassName` - note the `s` indicating it returns a collection and the ending is `ClassName`. You would then need to index into that collection before attempting to access the `Click` method

As there is only a single element with classname `button` you can use a faster [css class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) (this is also faster than using a type selector of `form`; likewise, you can use the faster css equivalent of `getElementById` for the other two DOM elements). [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectoraLL) stops at the first match so is also more efficient.

Finally, rather than hard coded waits use proper page load waits as shown below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WorldCheck()
    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.world-check.com/frontend/login/"

        While .busy Or .readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#username").Value = "ABCDEF" ' equivalent to .getElementbyID("username").Value = "ABCDEF"
            .querySelector("#password").Value = "GHIJKL" '.getElementbyID("password").Value = "GHIJKL"
            .querySelector(".button").Click
        End With

        While .busy Or .readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Stop                                     '<== delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```